# passing GET parameter from python view to template

Tags: python, django, view, parameters, get

As simple as this is, I'm having trouble getting the value of a GET parameter `d`

I'm clicking on a link like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Account/Site/d=mysite.com
```

The `view` that, that `url` serves is:

```
@login_required
def Site(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # verify domain in url is associated with authenticated users account
        DomainToScan = request.GET.get('d')
        VerifyDomainAgainstDb = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient=request.user,domainNm=DomainToScan)
    else:
        HttpResponseRedirect("/Login/")

    return render(request, 'VA/account/begin_site.html', {
        'Site':Site,
        'VerifyDomainAgainstDb':VerifyDomainAgainstDb                                                     
    })
```

specifically, this line:

```
DomainToScan = request.GET.get('d')
```

the value of `DomainToScan` is outputting as `None` when viewing the django template `begin_site.html`

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

```
urls.py

(r'^Account/Site/[?]d=[A-za-z0-9]{2,50}.[a-z]{1,3}$', Site),
```

For some reason this isn't matching a url like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Account/Site/?d=mysite.com
```

Any reason why? [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) says its valid

Comment: do you need a `?` before `d=mysite.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any GET parameters. If you want `domain` to be a GET parameter, your link should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Account/Site/?d=mysite.com` - notice the `?`.

(Also note you would need to actually *return* `HttpResponseRedirect()`, not just call it: but the whole checking of is_authenticated is pointless anyway because the function is decorated with login_required, so a non-authenticated user wouldn't even get into that view.)

Comment: I really do appreciate it when you comment on my posts - I learn stuff each time. I'm having an issue with my urls.py not matching. Any reason why? (See above please)

Comment: @CodeTalk querystring arguments are treated as ancillary to/in addition to the main URL path, so you need to update the regex in the URLConf to no longer expect the 'd' param.  ie, it should now become: `(r'^Account/Site/$', Site)`. NB: this means that when you can't use the `{% url %}` tag or `reverse()` to generate a URL with the 'd' argument in it any more - you'll need to add that bit (with the `?` after the main URL has been generated

Comment: @stevejalim - do you mean as far as the param. url is created in the view, it should include a 'd' GET var like: "<li><a class="scan" href="/Account/Site/?d={{ domain }}">Link</span></a></li>  ?

Comment: If you could please post an answer @stevejalim . Thank you

Comment: Ah, you're making links by hand - I'd assumed you were using the `url` template tag. What you're doing should work fine, but it's not best practice

Comment: Do you have a link for best practice for this? (I messed around with it some more and was able to get it - finally!)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
@login_required
def Site(request, DomainToScan=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # verify domain in url is associated with authenticated users account
        VerifyDomainAgainstDb = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient=request.user,domainNm=DomainToScan)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/Login/")
    return render(request, 'VA/account/begin_site.html', locals())
```

urls.py

```
(r'^Account/Site/(?P<DomainToScan>[^/]+)/', Site),
```